# Inexperienced with SQL - Access Violation

Tags: mysql, magento

I work for an IT company that does web hosting, and I - personally - am very inexperienced* with SQL.

*see awful

A client of mine is attempting to integrate an Epos system with his magento website, and during Epos' integration they are met with the following error.

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

He sent me through the following queries to input that he claims should rectify the situation:

```
GRANT CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES on * to 'cl54-cslstores'@'%';
GRANT CREATE VIEW on * to 'cl54-cslstores'@'%';
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE on * to 'cl54-cslstores'@'%';
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER on * to 'cl54-cslstores'@'%';
```

Apparently, those four snippets should fix his issue, however, when I run the commands, I receive the following error:

> SQL query:
>
> GRANT CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON * TO  'cl54-cslstores'@'%';
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1044 - Access denied for user 'cl54-cslstores'@'%' to database 'cl54-cslstores'

I'm using the Database as the administrator, so I don't understand how there is a permissions/access issue.

Again... I have absolutely no clue when working with SQL, so this may be a very easy fix, but I've had a look around on t'interwebs and couldn't find a solution that I could understand, let alone follow.

Is there any help that anyone could provide as to how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check the user that you are logged in as:

```
select user();
```

select_user will show you what you attempted to login as. Then run this query:

```
select current_user();
```

This will show you what you are actually connected as. You need to confirm that you are logged in as the root user - so root@localhost in mysql - if not you should log out and log in as the root user.

Now check the grant privileges for your user using the following query:

```
SELECT host, user, password, Grant_priv, Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
```

This will generate a list of the users, and at the end it will have the Grant priv set as Y or N. If you are set as N, then you can change the privelleges as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
```

You'll then need to flush the previous privileges and run the following sql commands.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

This links might be of use to you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36008/error-1044-access-denied-to-user

Hope that helps!

EDIT

You'll need to reset your root user account and then follow the instructions above, the info on how to do this in PhpMyAadmin is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Or

https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin

Comment: Thank you for responding. This has me tearing my hair out.
The database only has one user - cl54-cslstores

But when I try to do the SELECT and UPDATE commands, it says command denied to user.

I'm doing this through the phpMyAdmin panel.

Comment: When you run the select current_user(); does it show the root@localhost user? If not it could be that you don't have the correct admin rights set up.

Comment: No. It shows: "cl54-cslstores@%". This is the only user we made when making the database. I don't think a root user was created....

Comment: What do you get when you run this: SELECT host, user, password, Grant_priv, Super_priv FROM mysql.user; What's the exact error message?

Comment: After running that, I receive the following error: "#1142 - SELECT command denies to user 'cl54-cslstores'@'10.0.187.192' for table 'user'."
Many apologies if this is incredibly easy to fix and I'm just making it difficult, but I have no experience with SQL and have been thrown in the deep end.

Comment: Ok, you don't have the correct permissions. Every database comes with a root user - in order to reset the password follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin and then do my steps above. Edited my answer to have more detail :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance, however, none of those options seem viable. The database isn't stored on a local machine. I access it by going through a hosting website called Heart Internet. Then through heart I go to the databases and log into the PHPMyAdmin. We don't keep the Databases on a server.

Comment: Aggh, I see! I didn't realise there was a third party involved in this. I'd recommend getting in touch with Heart Internet and having them change the permissions for you. If they set the database up then it should be a quick change at the root level.

Comment: Thank you very much Hollie. I shall do that now :) Thank you for all your help.